# Animate a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uibutton

I wanted to know if is possible to have a UIButton which when untouched animates?

Not sure if that makes perfect sense.  I have a UIButton which I have placed via IB on my XIB.  I am using a type Custom with my own 75x75 image for control state default.  When the user touches the button i have no custom image set so it just darkens which is fine.

However, when the button is not touched, I would like it to animate between two or three different custom images to give it an effect of 'glowing' around the outer edges.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to go down to the Core Animation layer. The shadow property of the UIButton's layer is animatable, so you can create a repeating CABasicAnimation I change the shadow color/size and add it to the layer. The following code worked for me.

```
button.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectInset(button.bounds, -3, -3)] CGPath];
button.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowColor"];
animation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
animation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;

[button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadow"];
```

And attach these methods appropriate to the button's control events.

```
-(IBAction)userDidTouchDown:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [button.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"shadow"];
}

-(IBAction)userDidTouchUp:(UIButton *)sender
{

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowColor"];
    animation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    animation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;

    [button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadow"];
}
```

You can play around with the shadow values (particularly the path) to get it right for you. Don't forget to attach userDidTouchUp: with both the touch up inside and touch up outside events.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have a custom view, as UIButton cannot do animation.
UIView for the whole frame with two subviews:
Button on the bottom, uiimageview on top.

You set the animationImages property of the uiimageview to your frames.
Hide/show the uiimageview as needed.